# Inconsistent behaviour when calling join() in the destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

Considering the following code, where I declare a simple class for executing asynchronous/threaded operations:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class basic_executor {
 public:
    basic_executor() {
        _mx.lock();
        printf("Ctor @%p\n", this);
        _mx.unlock();
    }

    virtual ~basic_executor() {
        _mx.lock();
        printf("Dtor @%p\n", this);
        _mx.unlock();

        if (_thread.joinable()) {
            _thread.join();

            _mx.lock();
            printf("Joined thread @%p\n", this);
            _mx.unlock();
        }
    }

    // sync call
    void run() {
        start();
        execute();
        stop();
    }

    // async call
    void launch(bool detach = false) {
        // create packaged task
        std::packaged_task< void() > task([this] {
            start();
            execute();
            stop();
        });
        // assign future object to function return
        _done = task.get_future();
        // launch function on a separate thread
        _thread = std::thread(std::move(task));
        // detach them from main thread in order to avoid waiting for them
        if (detach == true) {
            _thread.detach();
        }
    }

    // blocking wait for async (detached/joinable)
    void wait() const {
        _done.wait();
    }

 protected:
    virtual void start()   { /* for derived types to implement */ }
    virtual void stop()    { /* for derived types to implement */ }
    virtual void execute() { /* for derived types to implement */ }

    std::mutex _mx;
    std::thread _thread;
    std::future< void > _done;
};
```

And using the following application example where I derive from it to create two logger objects that make dummy prints for a certain span of time:

```
class logger : public basic_executor {
 public:
    logger() { /* ... */}

    ~logger() {
        _mx.lock();
        std::cout << "logger destructor " << std::endl;
        _mx.unlock();
    }

    void execute() override {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            _mx.lock();
            printf("L1: I am printing something\n");
            _mx.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    }

    void stop() override {
        _mx.lock();
        printf("L1: I am done!\n");
        _mx.unlock();
    }
};


class logger2 : public basic_executor {
 public:
    logger2() { /* ... */}

    ~logger2() {
        _mx.lock();
        printf("logger2 destructor\n");
        _mx.unlock();
    }

    void execute() override {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            _mx.lock();
            printf("L2: I am ALSO printing something\n");
            _mx.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        }
    }

    void stop() override {
        _mx.lock();
        printf("L2: I am done!\n");
        _mx.unlock();
    }
};



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* code */

    // printf("log:\n");
    logger log1;

    // printf("log1:\n");
    logger2 log2;

    printf("----------------------------------!\n");

    log2.launch();
    log1.launch();

    // log1.wait();
    // log2.wait();

    printf("----------------------------------!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an unexpected behavior from the program:

```
Ctor @0x7fff8b18c990
Ctor @0x7fff8b18c9e0
----------------------------------!
----------------------------------!
logger2 destructor
Dtor @0x7fff8b18c9e0
Joined thread @0x7fff8b18c9e0
logger destructor 
Dtor @0x7fff8b18c990
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
L1: I am printing something
Joined thread @0x7fff8b18c990
```

in that *occasionally*, the 'log2' object never starts its execution before being destroyed, or the 'join()' call on its destructor hangs indefinitely. Is there any obvious reason why this happens, what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Re: "...declare a simple class..." -- it doesn't look at all simple to me. It looks like a Java design forced into C++ syntax, which is almost always a disaster. That aside, having a do-everything class means keeping track of a bunch of details, even when those details aren't involved in what an object is currently doing. The design of multi-threading in C++ deliberately did not take this route in order to avoid exactly these sorts of complexity-induced problems.

Comment: Your approach is flawed: When the baseclass destructor runs, the derived part of the object was already destroyed. This means that virtual functions don't call the derived class any more and that all member variables (!) had their destructors called. If you then wait for code to finish in the derived class, it's already too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug can occur with either logging class. However, with undefined behavior you have no guarantees whatsoever, and no expectation of any kind of consistent results. You've only, so far, observed the same bug with one of two logging classes. Although I can explain why is that, in practical terms, it is immaterial. The bug can happen with either of the objects. Let's begin here:

```
    _thread = std::thread(std::move(task));
```

You are not going to get any guarantees whatsoever that the new execution thread will immediately start executing any of the following before this code proceeds and returns from `launch()`:

```
    std::packaged_task< void() > task([this] {
        start();
        execute();
        stop();
    });
```

Most of the time, practically, this is going to start running pretty quickly, in the new execution thread. But you cannot rely on that. All that C++ guarantees you is that at some point ***after*** `std::thread` finishes constructing a new execution thread will start running. It may be immediate. Or, it may be a few hundred milliseconds later because your operating system had something more important on its plate.

You are expecting that the new execution thread will always start executing "immediately", simultaneous with `std::thread` getting constructed. That is not true. After all, you might be running with a single CPU core, and after constructing the `std::thread` object you're continuing to execute what follows in the same execution thread, and only a while later a context switch occurs, to the new execution thread.

Meanwhile:

1. `launch`() returns.
2. The parent execution thread reaches the end of `main()`.
3. All of the objects in the automatic scope are going to get destroyed, one by one.
4. In C++, when an object consists of a superclass and a subclass, the subclass gets destroyed first, followed by the superclass. This is how C++ works.
5. So, the `logger`/`logger2` subclass's destructor gets immediately invoked and it destroys the its object (just the `logger`/`logger2` subclass).
6. Now the superclass's destructor gets invoked, to destroy the superclass. `~basic_executor` starts doing its thing, patiently waiting.
7. And now, finally, that new execution thread, remember that one? Guess what: it finally starts running, and valiantly tries to execute `start()`, `execute()`, and `stop()`. Or maybe it managed to get through `start()`, first, but hasn't reached `execute()` yet. But since the actual logger subclass is already destroyed now, guess what happens? Nothing. It's gone. The subclass is no more. It ceased to be. It joined the choir invisible. It is pining for the fjords. It's an ex-subclass. There is no `logger::execute` or `logger2::execute()` any more.

Comment: This goes in line with what I was suspecting happens (i.e. the derived implementation no longer exist when `join()` is called), and I was indeed under the wrong impression that `std::thread` would start immediately. But is there any workaround to this, without having to call `join()` on the derived destructor (the whole point of `basic_executor` is to provide abstraction over thread programming)? Does `std::async` provides any improvement over `std::thread` in this aspect?

Comment: C++ gives no guarantees whatsoever, when it comes to execution threads. Besides, that is irrelevant. The fundamental problem is that you cannot destroy an object if there's an execution thread is either executing one of its methods, or is in the process of invoking its methods via virtual function dispatch. Your most derived class's destructor must wait for all execution threads to terminate, before destroying the object. Even if the execution thread started on time, the logger class gets destroyed before the superclass's destructor runs. Game over.

Comment: A question, if I may. In step 7, I could imagine two things happenning: a) the start/execute/stop calls get looked up in the vtable which still contains the old addresses for logger/logger2. In this case the methods would either be executed normally, because they use no instance variables of the destructed logger/logger2 (producing output), or we should see a crash. Or b) the vtable now points to the empty implementations of start/execute/stop in basic_executor, so nothing happens. But that would mean the subclass dtor adjusts the vtable, which would be unnecessary work in 99% of cases, no?

Comment: The answer is b). And it is not "unnecessary". It is, in fact, required by the C++ standard. The subclass does not exist anymore, only the superclass, so virtual dispatch must now work exactly the same way as if the subclass was never constructed. Finally, `vtable` is just an implementation detail, and its update is completely unsynchronized, and implementation-defined. Destruction ***or construction*** of an object, with another execution thread invoking its virtual method, is automatically undefined behavior.